# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: BulkWriteError: E11000 duplicate key error collection - MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

quick question. I have some JSON incoming and I am sending it off to a MongoDB collection. Because I need to constantly send new data coming in from the API off to the DB, I wrapped my `fetch` inside a `setInterval`.

The issue now, is that I need to send only the new and unique documents off to the DB (the ones that don't exist in the DB to avoid duplicates that is). It IS working on the DB side, it is only pushing the uniques into the collection, but in my terminal (node js), I am getting the aforementioned (title) error. If I am right, this means that I am getting yelled at that the incoming IDs already exist, but I am not sure why I keep getting the error in the terminal.

Here is my code:

```
// SEND ALL INCOMING QUAKES TO DATABASE FOR ARCHIVING:
const every_ten_mins = 600000;

setInterval(() => {         
    // GET ALL EARTHQUAKES
    fetch('https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_hour.geojson')

    .then(resp => resp.json())

    .then((json) => {
        console.log(json);

        // PUSH UNIQUE QUAKES TO DATABASE
        const eq_collection = db.collection('earthquake_tracker');

        json.features.forEach((el, idx) => {

            // SET AN INDEX FOR THE 'ID' FIELD SO THAT IT CAN BE UNIQUE
            eq_collection.createIndex({id: 1}, {unique: true})      
            try {
                eq_collection.insertMany(json.features); // INSERT ONLY UNIQUE QUAKES
            } catch(e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        });

    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));        

}, every_ten_mins);
```

Am I on the right track here? And if not, what am I doing wrong? I just want to push the new documents (unique) into the DB constantly according to the `setInterval`. Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: _"I am getting the aforementioned (title) error"_ Since you are trying to insert a document with a duplicate `id` field (you have unique index on it), it is normal to get the E11000 duplicate error. The console shows it because you have `console.log(e)` in the _catch_ block of the try-catch.

Comment: Also, you can have the `eq_collection.createIndex({id: 1}, {unique: true})` code outside the for-loop so that it gets executed once (but, it is not incorrect to execute the same create index .statement repeatedly).